# Windows service permissions

Tags: security, nservicebus

I have a NServiceBus 3.0 publisher which runs under a domain service account. The publisher has no external dependencies and locally the only dependencies are the input queue and ravendb.

I have granted the service account full control over the input queue.

When I add the service account into the local admin group the service starts fine. If I remove the service account from local admins I am getting an error in the system log on start up:

```
The BlahBlahBlah service failed to start due to the following error: 
Access is denied.
```

If I look in the security log the following 4 entries are written:

**Entry 1:**

```
A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       MYSERVER$
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x3e7
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
    Account Name:       svc_AppPrototype
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon GUID:     {a224c91b-adce-3a5b-ca32-32265f073d2b}

Target Server:
    Target Server Name: localhost
    Additional Information: localhost

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x1ec
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Network Address:    -
    Port:           -
```

**Entry 2:**

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       MYSERVER$
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Logon Type:         5

New Logon:
    Security ID:        MYDOMAIN\svc_AppPrototype
    Account Name:       svc_AppPrototype
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x9c6bfc2
    Logon GUID:     {a224c91b-adce-3a5b-ca32-32265f073d2b}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x1ec
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   MYSERVER
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

**Entry 3:**

```
Special privileges assigned to new logon.

Subject:
    Security ID:        MYDOMAIN\svc_AppPrototype
    Account Name:       svc_AppPrototype
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x9c6bfc2

Privileges:     SeImpersonatePrivilege
```

**Entry 4:**

An account was logged off.

```
Subject:
    Security ID:        MYDOMAIN\svc_AppPrototype
    Account Name:       svc_AppPrototype
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x9c6bfc2

Logon Type:         5
```

All entries are recorded during the service startup.

My question is what explicit permissions do I need to set to start this service without having the service account in the local admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still unresolved so we had to grant local admins permissions to our service account. Luckily this was just on our integration environment and we didn't encounter this issue in production.